# Cost of mobile application development using Jdeveloper MAF

Tags: ios, mysql, oracle-adf, oracle-maf

I don't know if this is the right forum to ask this question. As `JDeveloper / MAF` is freely downloadable, can apps developed on this platforms be freely placed and priced at the Apple or Google market place? I am asking about `stand-alone-device-db` apps and not the apps that will require backend databases, which has a price.

Nevertheless, if the backend database is like free,opensource `MySql` coupled with freely available `webservers like GlassFish or Apache`, will it cost anything for database apps developed and deployed in these platforms?

Pardon me if I am missing anything.

Thanks

Comment: Did you notice the capitalized print on your tags that say "DO NOT USE THIS TAG!? ?

Answer (score 1):

Development is indeed free but when releasing it isn't.
Here is an OTN topic about your question, it also includes a link to the pricing list: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3595029?start=0&tstart=0